# Replace a word from string which contains number or special symbol

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a below string.

```
String str = "Test!T Test1Test Test1 Test!";
```

Number of cases from this string :

> 1. `Test!T` : This word contains special charcater `!`.
> 2. `Test1Test` : This word contains number `1`.
> 3. `Test1` : This word contains number `1` at end of this word.
> 4. `Test!` : This word contains special character `!` at the end of this word.

Now I want to replace those word from the above string which contains character or number within word means `(case 1 and 2)` in my case Test!T and Test1Test will be replace by space.

Expected output : `Test1 Test!`

How can I replace 1 or 2 case from the defined string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple Regex like `[a-zA-Z]++\\S+[a-zA-Z]+` to achieve it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String str = "Test!T Test1Test Test1 Test!";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]++\\S+[a-zA-Z]+",""));
}
```

Output:

```
Test1 Test!
```

Comment: For extra note : special character can be anything. That can be ascii charater or special character

Comment: @Shiladittya Yes, you are right. I should be using a Metacharacter instead. Updated the solution. Thanks.